# Pascal Triangle general formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I'm working on a presentation on the Binomial Theorem for my Algebra 2 class and while writing Pascal's Triangle, I came across one of the properties that I haven't seen in a while.  That being
$$\sum_{k=1, k-j\ge0}^n\binom{k}{k-j}=\binom{n+1}{n-j}$$
I tried playing around with a proof and I'm having trouble because of the arbitrary value for $j$.  I also have tried to simplify it so that I don't need the condition under the summation, that being $k-j\ge0$.  For example, for $j=1, n=3$
$$1$$$$\color{red}{1} . . .1$$$$1...\color{red}{2}...1$$$$1...3...\color{red}{3}...1$$$$1...4...\color{green}{6}...4...1$$
$$\color{red}{\binom{1}{0}}+\color{red}{\binom{2}{1}}+\color{red}{\binom{3}{2}}=\binom{3+1}{3-1}=\color{green}{\binom{4}{2}}$$
However, if say $j=3$, then the first terms are negative, hence undefined, hence the need for the restriction.  So is there are way to get rid of the restriction for a generalized formula?

EDIT:  and no, the christmas tree theme was not intentional...but it is festive...

Comment: Consider them as zeros.  Again from the Pascal triangle assume that  it's surrounded by zeros, the formulas will be still valid.  In your example $\binom{4}{0} = \binom{3}{0} + \binom{3}{-1}+\binom{3}{-2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1, k-j\ge0}^n\binom{k}{k-j}=\binom{n+1}{n-j} \iff \sum_{k=j}^n \binom{k}{j}= \binom{n+1}{j+1} $$

This last identity can be shown using $\displaystyle {n\choose r}={n-1\choose r-1}+{n-1\choose r} $ applied repeatedly:

\begin{align}
LHS &= {j\choose j}+{j+1\choose j}+{j+2\choose j}+\cdots+{n \choose j} \\
&= {j+1\choose j+1}+{j+1\choose j}+{j+2\choose j}+\cdots+{n \choose j} \\
&= {j+2\choose j+1}+{j+2\choose j}+\cdots+{n \choose j} \\
& \cdots \cdots \cdots \cdots\\
&= {n+1 \choose j+1}
\end{align}

Comment: very nice. I've seen that identity as well and 1) never took the time to understand it in regards to the triangle 2) should have let the restriction be $k=j$.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.  It is called Hockeystick identity IIRC because of the shape the coloured numbers make on the Pascal's triangle

Comment: Ha...that's awesome.  I've never heard it called that and now I'll never forget.  I think my kids will like the idea (the theory and notation is way above them).